# SPF problem with incoming emails

Tags: sendmail, spf

I use sendmail MTA and dovecot and have SPF configured, my domain txt entries:

> xx.pl descriptive text "IN" "v=spf1
>   ip4:x.x.x.x ip4:x.x.x.x ip4:x.x.x.x
>   ip4:x.x.x.x a:mail.yy.pl a:mis.xx.pl
>   a:smtp-out.yy.pl mx -all" xx.pl
>   descriptive text "v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.x6
>   ip4:x.x.x.x ip4:x.x.x.x ip4:x.x.x.x
>   a:mail.yy.pl a:mis.xx.pl
>   a:smtp-out.yya.pl"

and i get many emails with such text in logs:

> Milter add: header: Received-SPF: None
>   (xx.xx.pl: domain of
>   center.xx.pl\n\tdoes not designate
>   permitted sender hosts)\n\t
>   receiver=xx.xx.pl;
>   client-ip=xx.xx.xx.xx;\n\tenvelope-from=center.xx.pl;
>   helo=center.xx.pl

and it looks like emails that should be accepted and delivered.

Do you know what should i do to get it working? I guess it is something with my SPF conf..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your SPF record is for the servers **sending** email on behalf of your domain, it has absolutely nothing to do with receiving email from other domains.  If you're having a problem with incoming email look elsewhere.

Secondly, you cannot split your SPF record like that, you'd need to use `include:` instead, and ideally use only IP addresses instead of a mix of IP addresses and hostnames.  For further advice about your SPF record you should provide your actual domain name, or use the SPF mailing list (but do follow BillThor's advice).

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your configurate with a testing site such as http://tools.bevhost.com/spf/.  This is from the [OpenSPF.org](http://www.openspf.org/Project_Overview) site.  They also have a tool to help build your SPF record.

EDIT: You have a large list of servers.  You should only have a few servers sending email directly to the Internet.  Only servers sending email directly to the Internet (boarder servers) need to be listed.  All internal servers should relay out through these servers.

If you have roaming users, then setup authenticate access on the submission port for them to send email.

If your domain is being used to send spam, then you may be getting backscatter from poorly configured servers.